# spring el: trouble with parameters

Tags: java, spring-el

There is a web-service method annotated as @Preautorize

```
@PreAuthorize("principal.somePrincipalMethod(#request.property1, #request.property2, 'stringA', 'stringB')")
public SomeResponse someWebServiceMethod(SomeRequest request) {
...
}
public class SomeRequest {
    Long property1;
    Long property2;
}
```

And there are two overloaded methods of class implements UserDetails

```
public boolean somePrincipalMethod(Long longParam1, Long longParam2, String... stringParams) {
    return true;
}
public boolean somePrincipalMethod(Long longParam, String... stringParams) {
    return true;
}
```

When I call `someWebServiceMethod` I get `somePrincipalMethod(Long longParam, String... stringParams)` not `somePrincipalMethod(Long longParam1, Long longParam2, String... stringParams)`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution (workaround).

```
@PreAuthorize("principal.somePrincipalMethod(#request.property1, #request.property2, {'stringA', 'stringB'})")
public SomeResponse someWebServiceMethod(SomeRequest request) {
...
}
public boolean somePrincipalMethod(Long longParam1, Long longParam2, String[] stringParams) {
    return true;
}
public boolean somePrincipalMethod(Long longParam, String[] stringParams) {
    return true;
}
```